# The "Evan" Numbers

Tags: number-sequence, no-computers

The Even numbers are simple: $2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, \dots$

The "Evan" numbers follow a tricky rule: $2, 4, 6, 30, 32, 34, 36, 40, 42, 44, 46, 50, 52, 54, 56, 60, 62, 64, 66, 2000, 2002, 2004, \dots$

What is going on?

Filler text: Lorem ipshum dolior sit amet, consecteturn adipiscting elitt, sedh do eiusemod tempor incididunet uta laborre ete dolorne magona aliquha. Ut enimu and minim vendiam, quirs nostrude exercitation dullamco laboris nisi ut saliquip

Comment: What's with the filler text?

Comment: @FireCubez What about it?

Comment: What is its use? The accepted answer didn't even mention it. Am I missing something?

Comment: The filler text is so the question can reach the minimum character count.

Comment: No, actually it's a hint.

Comment: @a guy @Glorfindel Both of you are correct.

Comment: Isn't this just straight out taken from [the recent numberphile video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OeGSQggDkxI)? Which is named "Eban numbers". Vote to close?

Comment: actually this should be called avan numbers, as there's an e in evan ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Evan" numbers are

> numbers not containing the letter 'e' (when written in English).

That means they

> don't contain the following words:
>  - one
>  - three
>  - five
>  - seven(ty)
>  - eight(y)
>  - nine(ty)
>  - ten/teen
>  - twelve
>  - twenty
>  - hundred

Interestingly,

> the OEIS calls them 'eban numbers': see sequence [A006933](http://oeis.org/A006933)
>  FWIW, I found the pattern on my own, I didn't use a computer or phone to look it up.

---

As for the filler text,

> it's the standard [Lorem Ipsum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorem_ipsum) with some letters interjected:
>  Lorem ips**h**um dol**i**or sit amet, consectetur**n** adipisc**t**ing elit**t**, sed**h** do eius**e**mod tempor incididun**e**t ut**a** labor**r**e et**e** dolor**n**e mag**o**na aliqu**h**a. Ut enim**u** a**n**d minim ven**d**iam, qui**r**s nostrud**e** exercitation **d**ullamco laboris nisi ut **s**aliquip
>  hinttheearenohundreds (which seems to miss an r, BTW)
>  Hint: there are no hundreds (because that word contains an 'e').